# Angular form fields get validated if any button gets clicked inside form

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I've got an Angular Material Reactive Form in my example with some simple inputs and validations. I've built in two buttons: one outside, one inside the `form` tag. Can anyone tell me why the whole form gets validated if clicked on the button inside the `form`?

How can I block the validation in this case?

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m4kar5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [default button attribute type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type) is "submit", so you need to **set button type to button** to achieve your requirement.

```html
<button type="button">Click me and watch everything gets validated</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `button` inside the form, has by default the property `type="submit"`.
If you have more than one button inside a `form` tag, you must specify the type :

```html
<form>
  <button>Submit the form</button> <!-- Default is submit -->

  <button type="button">Some random action</button>

  <button type="reset">Reset a form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is right too, but the other guy was faster and had a source. But I appreciate your help!